# Tablet with easily used file explorer for loading pdf files

Tags: tablet

I usually try to be pretty vague, but I think details will help here.

My wife needs a mobile device that she can put in her clipboard and take with her at work. She works in schools (at district level) and sometimes needs to show technical information to teachers. However, her job has her covering more than one school location, all subject areas and all grades. Printing out this information and bringing it along wouldn't be possible.

Her issued laptop is too bulky to walk around all day with and the organization will not be providing this hardware. So I will be procuring it and setting it up for her.

---

**File Management might look something *like* this**

```
 1) ALL FILES
   A) Elementary School
     i) First Grade
        (1) Science.pdf
        (2) Math.pdf
        (3) Reading.pdf
     ii) Second Grade
        (1) Science.pdf
        ..etc
  B)  Middle School
  C)  High School
```

---

**Requirements**

- Probably no larger than 10" screen, keep it light but still easy to read
- Easily used file explorer
- Capable of loading & rendering the pdf files (Maybe other file types, but not necessary)
- Hopefully easy to back out of the pdf files to the file explorer to select another pdf file
- Decent battery life - it doesn't need to last a week on standby or anything, but charging it everyday wouldn't be great
- I'll load the files on locally
- I think it would need to be able to show color on screen
- Touch screen

**Non-requirements**

- She won't be able to get on wifi in the secure environments so that's a non-issue
- Audio isn't important
- Peripherals aren't important, no need to have a keyboard or anything

---

If need be, I can load an O/S on whatever device, if that's what's best, as long as it remains simple to use. She is tech savvy.

Not really sure on budget, just something that would work. Cheaper is better, maybe keep it under $300 USD.

Comment: Any chance IT could issue her a 2-in-1 instead of her current laptop? Seems like that'd massively simplify things.

Comment: @JMY1000 That would be nice, but no - "they" are not flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File explorer, PDF reader, etc, are not issues for nowadays tablets, every single one can do it.

Now if you're looking for a tablet around 10" with a good battery life, Huawei Mediapad M5 Lite could be great. I bet it is even totally overkill for just displaying some PDF files.

A ~120-140 USD tablet would still be more than enough, like a Samsung Galaxy Tab A 10.1 2016 or a Lenovo Tab 4 10.1.

Then install a decent file explorer like ES Explorer or whatever you want, and a PDF reader if it does not have one already, and that's done.